# Mongodb on Kubernetes exceed memory limit - Available memory is less than system memory

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I tried to run Mongodb on Kubernetes. However it always got Evicted every 1-2 minutes.
I tried to run the image in docker and worked fine. Do I need to make special configuration?

deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb1
  namespace: xxxxx
  labels:
    app: mongodb1
    env: dev1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb1
      env: dev1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb1
        env: dev1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb1
        image: xxxx/mongo:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: Asis/Bangkok
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
          value: blockchaindb
        tty: true
        stdin: true
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2Gi
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: xxxx
```

I tried to use the config file and rename the image name. So, I created a Dockerfile. Here is my DockerFile.

```
FROM mongo:latest

MAINTAINER TEST

COPY ./mongo-init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
COPY ./mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf
RUN mkdir /var/lib/mongodb


RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb \
    && CREATE_FILES=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* \
    && for f in $CREATE_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done \
    && mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --shutdown \
    && chown -R mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

CMD mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

I set up wiredTigerCacheSize to 512M, but the logs still show systemMemorySize 60G.

cache_size=512M

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-18T02:25:08.651+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=512M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
```

Logs "systemMemSizeMB":64380

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-18T02:25:08.648+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20720,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Available memory is less than system memory","attr":{"availableMemSizeMB":2048,"systemMemSizeMB":64380}}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `evict`? can you show the errors if any? what is the pod state?

Comment: the pod status showed Evicted, then it created a new pod. I found this in the kubectl logs "{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-16T11:53:50.167+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20720,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Available memory is less than system memory","attr":{"availableMemSizeMB":2048,"systemMemSizeMB":64380}}"    Not sure. does it help?

Comment: I just found the mongodb option storage: wiredTiger: engineConfig: cacheSizeGB:. I will try to set this one first.

Comment: yes, so it looks like the pod is requesting for `2Gi` but your `availableMemSizeMB` is also 2048MB, try reducing the requests memory to `1Gi`

Comment: you might also have to look at the setting for this flag `systemMemSizeMB` which I believe should be less than the memory allocated to the pod.

Comment: Try to debug the image. It seems that it tries to use more memory than allocated. 1) Add a sleep as the entrypoint to the mongo image. 2) Bash into the docker container and run the command to start mongo manually. 3) Use topas or similar utility to check the memory consumption during the 1-2. 4) Also check the events of the pod that is evicted for extra hints on what is going on.

Comment: @PaulChibulcuteanu I am still checking if it is what you advise. I added a config file to limit mongo memory. the minimum that I can't limit was 60GB. "msg":"Available memory is less than system memory","attr":{"availableMemSizeMB":40960,"systemMemSizeMB":64380}}  I also attached the dockerfile, in case there was something wrong.

Comment: Did advices of @PaulChibulcuteanu helped ? Did you find solution ?

Comment: I had the same error. I added the code below to my docker file, and it worked. Make sure that the `wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` is less than the memory limit you set up for your mongo server.
```yaml
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        command: ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        args: ["mongod", "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", "0.25"]        
```